# Pasar el valor de una variable de un Screen a otro Scren en Kivy - Pyhon

Tags: python, kivy, screen

Tengo una App en Python con Kivy. Hay una pantalla para conceder acceso (login) a la app que consulta a una BBDD y da el Ok si está registrado. La app usa Kivy con el widget Screen, que pasa de una ventana a otra con un ActionBar.

El problema es que no soy capaz de pasar el valor de la variable "Usuario" cuando cambio de pantalla, para que me muestra ese valor en el ActionBar de la pantalla Screen en la que se está actualmente.

En la pantalla/Screen  sí que aparece en el ActionBar el nombre de usuario actual, una vez que está autenticado. Sin embargo en las no soy capaz de que aparezca.

A ver si alguien puede echarme una mano!. Gracias

```
Fichero Usuario.py

class Login(Screen):
    nombre_usuario = StringProperty("")
    def entrar(self):
    conexion = pymysql.connect(host="", user="",passwd="", db="")   
    cursor = conexion.cursor()      
    user_login = self.ids["login"].text
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users where user_login = 
 {}'".format(user_login))
    data = cursor.fetchall()

    if len(data) == 0:
        #if "'{}'".format(self.search_input_email.text).exists():
        print("No existe el usuario: ", self.ids["login"].text)
        self.ids["login"].text = ''
    else:   
        print("Existe el usuario: ", self.ids["login"].text)
        self.nombre_usuario_1 = self.ids["login"].text
        self.ids["login"].text = ''

        self.nombre_usuario = self.nombre_usuario_1
        return self.nombre_usuario

class Documentacion(Screen):
    def usuario(self):
        usuario = Login()
        self.nombre_usuario_1 = StringProperty("")
        self.nombre_usuario_1 = usuario.nombre_usuario
        return self.nombre_usuario_1
```

```
Fichero Usuario.kv

<Login>:
    name: "login"
    ActionBar:
        pos_hint: {'top':1}
        #Background color, in the format (red, green, blue, a).
        background_color: (1.0, 3.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        pos_hint: {'top':1}
        ActionView:
            use_separator: True
            ActionPrevious:
                title: ''
                with_previous: True
                on_press: 
                    app.root.current = 'menu_principal'    
            ActionButton:
                #Coloco el usuario que está activo
                text: "Usuario: " + root.nombre_usuario



<Documentacion>
    name: "documentacion"
    #Cabecera de ActionBar
    ActionBar:
        pos_hint: {'top':1}
        #Background color, in the format (red, green, blue, a).
        background_color: (1.0, 3.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        ActionView:
            use_separator: True
            ActionPrevious:
                title: ''
                with_previous: True
                on_press: 
                    app.root.current = 'menu_principal'
            ActionButton:
                #Coloco el usuario que está activo
                text: "Usuario: " + str(root.usuario())
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Mira este ejemplo de un CheckBox que lleva el dato de un screen a otro screen, con alguna pequeña modificación te podría dar la idea de como hacer el tuyo.

Código .py

```
...

gender1 = StringProperty("")

def insert_data(self):

    self.ids['button_1'].text = format(self.gender1)

...
```

Código .kv

```
ScreenManager:
    id: manager
    size_hint: 1, .9999

    Screen:
        name: 'main'
...

Button:
    id: button_1
    text: "?"
    font_size:10
    on_press: root.ids.manager.current = '1'

....

Screen:
    name: '1'

...

Label:
    id:label_r
    text: "R"
    text_size: self.size
    halign:'center'
    valign: 'middle'

CheckBox:
    id : chk
    text: "R"
    on_active:
        root.gender1 = self.text


Button:
    id: Button_Aceptar
    text: 'Aceptar'
    on_press: root.insert_data()
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Después de darle vueltas, he hecho algo parecido pero con la función on_pre_enter(). Dejo el código.

Comment: Me alegra mucho @Javier, espero que califiques mi respuesta positivamente.

Answer (score 0):

main.py

```
__version__ = "1.0"

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Screen1(Screen):
    name_x = StringProperty('')
    def update_info(self):
        self.name_x = self.ids.nombre.text
        print(self.name_x)

class Screen2(Screen):
    names = StringProperty('')
    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        self.names = "Hola : " + self.manager.ids.Screen1.name_x 

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<ScreenManagement>:
    Screen1:
        id: Screen1
    Screen2:
        id: Screen2

<Screen1>:
    name: "Screen_1"
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "nombre"
        TextInput:
            id: nombre
        Button:
            text: "Ver saludo"
            on_release:
                root.update_info()
                root.manager.current = "Screen_2"

<Screen2>:
    name: 'Screen_2'
    Button:
        text: root.names
        on_release: 
            root.manager.current = quit() #"Screen_1"
        font_size: 50
```

Comment: Deberias de explicar como es que esto resuelve lo que plantea la pregunta.

Comment: Responde a la pregunta pasando un valor de la pantalla Screen1 a la pantalla Screen2

Answer (score -1):

Si lo que quieres es compartir una variable entre los dos Screen de python lo puedes hacer de varias maneras una es usando memoria compartida o tuberías en python.
Revisa estos links te pueden ser utilidad:

https://www.python-course.eu/pipes.php
https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/multiprocessing-comunicacion-entre-procesos/
https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html

Comment: Se te agradece la ayuda, pero responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad

Comment: Hola Alexander. Lo que planteas es para compartir información entre procesos. El concepto Screen en kivy no tiene nada que ver con distintos procesos, ni siquiera son ventanas distintas al uso dentro de un mismo proceso, son en realidad una subclase de RelativeLayout que son mostradas y manejadas mediante el widget ScreenManager dentro de una misma ventana de la aplicación: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html